# How to remove chrome app icons from launchpad?

Tags: applications, google-chrome, launchpad

I uninstalled Google chrome by deleting it from the Applications folder and I also deleted the associated profile data from `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`.

But I have failed to remove all the Chrome apps icons from launchpad.

I would greatly appreciate it if you can point to the location where google is keeping those app launchers. I have looked for them in the hidden folders as well as Google folders in `~/Library` but I have had no luck.

Comment: Did you try searching Google?  Have a look at: [How to Remove Apps from Launchpad in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/05/remove-apps-from-launchpad/)

Comment: The Google chrome icons don't show "x" items when pushing the option key as described in the linked page.

Comment: @user3439894 - this is the top hit when searching Google

Comment: uninstalling the extension worked for me, took some time to refresh the launchpad

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/996729/how-do-i-remove-chromes-bundled-apps-from-mac-os-x-and-the-launchpad-gmail-go

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Open Finder, select Go/Go to Folder... (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>), paste in:

```
~/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized
```

Delete the apps from there.

(Note that `~` means your user folder, *not* the regular Applications folder which is at `/Applications` without `~`.)

Finally, **empty the trash** to remove from launchpad.

*If you use Chrome Canary:* it will have its own additional folder in `~/Applications`.

Comment: Hi, I've remove the chrome apps as described in the above answer, and now i want to restore them. However, i couldn't do so even if re-installing chrome all over again. the folder ~/Application/Chrome Apps.localized still missing. any idea how it can be solved ?

Comment: @Zohar81 - reinstall them using the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps).

Comment: Awesome! this was simple and straight. Thank you!

Answer (score 31):

1. Go to Finder
2. Open your home folder (i.e. "/Users//")
3. Open "Applications"
4. You should be able to see a folder named "Chrome Apps"

Either you can delete this folder or open it and delete the apps one by one.

Comment: Thanks, thats it! You have to delete the apps form the trash too.

Answer (score 7):

How to delete an app, removing it from Finder, Launchpad and Dock Menu:

*Keep in mind that this permanently deletes the apps in question from your Mac.*

1. Drag the app from launchpad and add it to the dock menu
2. Right click app on the dock menu, choose 'Options' then 'Open in finder'
3. Once in Finder, right click on the app and choose 'Move to trash'.
4. Finally, just grab the app from the dock and let it go in the middle of the desktop. You should see a dissolve cloud and hear a poof-like sound.

You can then empty your 'Trash' whenever you wish.  I chose to do it immediately after.

Here is a minute long video that gives a good visual: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQwjGqR34ZU

Comment: it is really simple!

Answer (score 3):

I think launchpad icons are in a database. You can find the database with `find /private/var/folders -name com.apple.dock.launchpad`. There will be one database per user.

Then use `sqlite3 /private/var/folders/your_db/db/db "delete FROM apps WHERE title='Google Drive';"` to delete the icons.

Comment: This feels so dirty, like messing with the registry in Windows. But it worked for me after nothing else did, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you open your User>(Your username)>Applications> folder (not the /Applications folder), you'll see a folder called "Chrome Apps".

All the apps, including the Chrome Launcher app are in here. You can delete them at will and they will be removed from your Dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Terminal, you can find typing Spotlight in "Terminal", and copy and paste this sentence there:

```
rm -r /Users/$USER/Applications/Chrome\ Apps.localized/
```

Answer (score 1):

I found easiest way to delete this chrome created apps from lunched. All you have to do is click on finder from the doc, then on the finder window there is a search bar, now search each name of the apps, like youtube, and you will see on the application part similar icon comes up. drag and trash it. Thats all. You don't need any codings.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Chrome, you can navigate to `chrome://apps`, and right-click to *Remove from Chrome*. This also will remove from launchpad automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Go to finder, click on the applications folder and drag google chrome into the trash. Once this is done, just empty the trash :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just remove from only the Dock, you can drag it off launch pad until it show "remove" word and let go.

To remove from launch pad, there needs to be uninstalling of the app.

To uninstall, I found there's a bug to work around as well.

1. if you `chrome://apps/` in your Chrome browser URL, and then right-click and uninstall that would remove from everywhere.

[image]

2. Otherwise you could delete from `~/Applications/Chrome Apps`, but I found it wouldn't delete from the Chrome's apps list.